# Why do I need to call an object from another module twice?

Tags: javascript, object, module

I have a module called UI.js, where I:

```
import todoManager from './toDoCreator.js';
```

and the other module toDoCreator.js:

```
const todoManager = {
    todos: [],
```

with other functions such as createTodo, editTodo, etc. In that module, in the end, I export:

```
export default { todoManager };
```

Then on the first module, UI, I do things like:

```
getDom().todoModalSaveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => todoManager.todoManager.editTodo(caller.id));
```

or

```
const todoBeingEdited = todoManager.todoManager.todos[todoId];
```

I tried writing the name only once (todoManager.doWhateverIwantFromThatObject) but it doesn't work. Why do I need to write the object twice?

Using webpack, I don't know if that changes anything.
Thanks!

Comment: `export default { todoManager };` - don't do that. You want `export const todoManager = { todos: … };` and `import { todoManager } from …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use export default:

```
export default todoManager;
```

Then you use import:

```
import todoManager from 'todoManager';
```

If you use export:

```
export todoManager;
```

Then

```
import {todoManager} from 'todoManager';
```

Comment: Your second and third snippets are syntax errors